# OpenGL shadowmapping артефакты на дальних расстояних (всенаправленные тени)

Tags: c++, opengl, графика, glsl

Проблема в том, что в тени на большом расстоянии появляются артефакты. Я хочу попробовать сделать буфер логарифмической глубины, но не понимаю, где это нужно делать и как ... Использую всенаправленную карту теней

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

вершинный шейдер:

```
#version 460 core
layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPos;

uniform mat4 model;
uniform float zCoef;
//out vec4 pos;

void main() {
    gl_Position = model * vec4(aPos, 1.0f);
//    gl_Position.z = log2(max(1e-6, gl_Position.w + 1.0)) * zCoef - 1.0;
//    gl_Position.z *= gl_Position.w;
}
```

геометрический шейдер:

```
#version 460 core
layout (triangles) in;
layout (triangle_strip, max_vertices = 18) out;

uniform mat4 shadowMatrices[6];
uniform float zCoef;

out vec4 FragPos; // FragPos from GS (output per emitvertex)

void main()
{
    for(int face = 0; face < 6; ++face)
    {
        gl_Layer = face; // встроенная переменная, указывающая на то, какую грань мы рендерим
        for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) // для каждой вершины треугольника
        {
            FragPos = gl_in[i].gl_Position;
            gl_Position = shadowMatrices[face] * FragPos;
//            gl_Position.z = log2(max(1e-6, gl_Position.w + 1.0)) * zCoef - 1.0;
//            gl_Position.z *= gl_Position.w;
            EmitVertex();
        }
        EndPrimitive();
    }
}
```

фрагментный шейдер:

```
#version 460 core
in vec4 FragPos;

uniform vec3 lightPos;
uniform float farPlane;
uniform float zCoef;

void main() {
    float lightDistance = length(FragPos.xyz - lightPos);

    lightDistance = lightDistance / farPlane;

    gl_FragDepth = lightDistance;
}
```

Comment: Боюсь так не получится. Перейдя на "логарифмический" z-буфер вы получите артефакты на всех расстояниях. Что вы можете сделать - это рендерить разные планеты с разными установками z-near, z-far. Это решит проблему с тенями. Полученные картинки придётся накапливать в буфере чтобы ближние планеты могли заслонять дальние.